# Tableau census tract highlighting multiple tracts

Tags: spatial, tableau-desktop

I'm trying to create a map based on census tract data in tableau. I have my dataset and I downloaded the shapefiles for the year I need here https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2018&layergroup=Census+Tracts
I set the relationship and then the geometry and names but when I mouseover some of the tracts, several are highlighted with the same name despite being distinctly different tracts. I'm somewhat new to spatial vis on tableau so I'm wondering if there is a common mistake I'm making and how I can avoid this from happening?